# Reliable way to trigger one-way CSS transition?

Tags: javascript, css

I have designed a transition that changes instantly background color, then slowly recovers to original color:

```css
body, html {margin: 0px;padding: 0px;}
div {
    padding: 3px;
    margin: 1px 0 1px 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: #3377FF;
    transition: background-color .9s ease-in;
}

div:hover {
    background-color: #33FF11;
    transition-duration: 0s;
}
```

```html
<div> Hello</div>
<div> Hello</div>
```

This is designed for row in a table to notify user of a change. I'd like to trigger effect this programmatically, but by using the actual CSS.

```
Row.prototype.blink = function() {
    ... ?
}
```

I tried to use `setTimeout` to add and remove class name from the nodes:

```js
$("div").on("click", function() {
    $(this).addClass("updated");
    var _this = this;
    setTimeout(function(){$(_this).removeClass("updated");}, 30);
});
```

```css
body, html {margin: 0px;padding: 0px;}
div {
    padding: 3px;
    margin: 1px 0 1px 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: #3377FF;
    transition: background-color .9s ease-in;
}

div.updated {
    background-color: #33FF11;
    transition-duration: 0s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Click div to activate the blink effect:</p>


<div> Hello</div>
<div> Hello</div>
```

I also tried to use the [`transitioned`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/transitionend) event, but the event doesn't ever trigger:

```
$("div").on("click", function() {
    $(this).one("transitionend", function(){$(this).removeClass("updated");}); // never happens
    $(this).addClass("updated");
});
```

I don't like the setTimeout method, can't you think of better trick to trigger the *blink* effect?

Comment: You can use `setTimeout`. Code: `var $this = $(this); $this.addClass("updated"); setTimeout(function() { $this.removeClass('updated'); }, 900);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason the `transitionend` event isn't being triggered is because `transition-duration` is set to `0s`. In other words, the transition never begins until the class is removed (but the class isn't removed because the event isn't fired).

It really sounds like an animation would be better suited for this. Just listen to the `animationend` event and remove the class in the callback when the animation ends:

```js
$('div').on('click', function() {
  $(this).addClass('updated').one('animationend', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('updated');
  });
});
```

```css
body, html {margin: 0px;padding: 0px;}
div {
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 1px 0 1px 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #3377FF;
  cursor: pointer;
}

div.updated {
  animation: updatedFade .9s ease-in forwards;
}

@keyframes updatedFade {
  0% { background-color: #33FF11; }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Hello</div>
<div>Hello</div>
```

As a work-around to your initial solution, you *could* change the `transition-duration` to something extremely short, like `1ms`, so that the initial transition is actually started, thereby allowing the `transitionend` event to be fired:

```js
$("div").on("click", function() {
  $(this).addClass("updated").one("transitionend", function() {
    $(this).removeClass("updated");
  });
});
```

```css
body, html {margin: 0px;padding: 0px;}
div {
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 1px 0 1px 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #3377FF;
  transition: background-color .9s ease-in;
  cursor: pointer;
}
div.updated {
  background-color: #33FF11;
  transition-duration: 1ms;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Hello</div>
<div>Hello</div>
```

Comment: @TomášZato Yep. You can actually just omit it. See the update.